# How do you remove the "box head" in a Facebook application?

Tags: facebook

I'm currently developing a Facebook application which will eventually end up on a Facebook Page. The problem is that I don't know how to remove the box header (handle?) with the application name and the close-button.

I've seen other applications on Pages being able to remove the header. Look at Apples Page here: http://www.facebook.com/home.php#/pages/Apple-Students/11147074409

Is it because they use an IFrame? I've tried that as well but I still need to call setFBML and embed an IFrame inside it.

Comment: I think you should write an email to facebook asking them about it. They are very helpful and have always responded to my emails. I think it is developers@facebook.com

Fill in the form here:
http://www.facebook.com/developers/developer_help.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found out how to get an IFrame without a header just like Apple does.

You have to sign a special deal with Facebook to get it... however this deal doesn't come cheap so it's out of question for most companies. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right about the IFrame in the Apple page.  It looks like the entire left column is a single IFrame.  Still, it's not clear how they managed to get rid of the handle bar.  Now I'm curious too...

Answer (score 0):

Is is possible that Apple paid facebook to remove the header you are talking about?

Maybe it's a special case and they have a special API/UI for people who are willing to give them cash money?

Comment: That is what I thought too ... I do know of several instance where FB has provided custom tools and resources to large organisations.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Facebook application a while back and I do not believe it has what you are calling a box header on it:  http://apps.facebook.com/photoisland/.  The application is configured to run entirely in an IFrame and I am not using FBML at all.